# Rails #url_for repeats namespace prefix when resolving a url for a namespaced nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

Greetings everyone,

I've the following:

`routes.rb`:

```
 namespace :hr do
    resources :employees do
      resources :skills
    end
  end
```

And those models:
`hr/skills.rb`

```
class Hr::Skill < ApplicationRecord
end
```

`hr/employees.rb`:

```
class Hr::Employee < ApplicationRecord

end
```

I'm trying to make `#url_for` resolve to `hr_employee_skills_path(@employee, @skill)`. I need `#url_for` to work that way because it's internally used by `#simple_form_for` within SimpleForm.

I tried different combinations of `#url_for` to give me the desired url path generator but none worked:

```
url_for [Hr::Employee.new, Hr::Skill.new]
NoMethodError: undefined method `hr_employee_hr_skills_url' for main:Object
```

Also this:

```
url_for [:hr, Hr::Employee.new, Hr::Skill.new]
NoMethodError: undefined method `hr_hr_employee_hr_skills_url' for main:Object
```

I just need `#url_for` to call  `hr_employee_skills_path(employee, skill)` so that it resolves to the actual route. How could that be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the link, but there is an option for the module that you can use to help with this:

```
module Hr
  def self.use_relative_model_naming?
    true
  end
end
```

This then allows for this:

```
url_for([:hr, Hr::Employee.first, Hr::Skill.first, only_path: true])
 => "/hr/employees/1/skills/1"
```

https://coderwall.com/p/heed_q/rails-routing-and-namespaced-models

Comment: I'm working on a large project with multiple units using completely unrelated models; unfortunately model namespaces might be necessary.

Comment: I updated the original answer since the original response was not something you could use in your scenario.